# javascript / jQuery - match a function from array of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

so I have a array of functions like this one:

```
var functions = [
   func1 = function(){ ... },
   func2 = function(){ ... },
   func3 = function(){ ... }
] ;
```

If I call a function like `functions[func1]()` it works, but if I call it like `functions['func1']()` it doesn't.

What's the difference?

And how can I call a function using the 2nd method (match the function name with a string)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be an object containing keys:

```
var functions = {
   func1: function(){ ... },
   func2: function(){ ... },
   func3: function(){ ... }
};
```

This will allow `functions['func1']()` to work.

I don't know how your `functions[func1]()` ever worked, though.

Your original code would have (inadvertently) created global variables (`func1`, etc) but those wouldn't have been valid indices into the `functions` array.

Comment: can I still use array like indexes on it? like `functions[5]` or `functions[functions.length]` etc?

Comment: Only if you also do something like: `functions[0] = functions.func1` for each element.  NB: array offsets start at zero.

Comment: but there are too many, I don't want to make the code so big :( Is there any way I could randomly pick a function from that object? (this is why I asked about the indexes)

Comment: Sure, pick a random number as an offset into the array returned by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(functions)`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call a random function, try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/DpzXS/)):

```
var functions = [
   [ function(el){ el.html('function 1'); } ],
   [ function(el){ el.html('function 2'); } ],
   [ function(el){ el.html('function 3'); } ]
],

    random = Math.round(Math.random() * functions.length),
    output = $('#display');

functions[random][0](output);
```

Comment: Why are you nesting all the functions in arrays?

Comment: @js1568: Because in the follow up comments, Alex asked if it was possible to pick a function using a random index.

Answer (score 1):

```
var functions = {   
                func1: function(){ ... },   
                func2: function(){ ... },   
                func3: function(){ ... }
};
```